# Automatic updating timer in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to make an website with an little counter on the main site. The user should press a button and the timer should count the time since the button was pressed. The time should always visible for the user and updated every second.

Is there a gem or a example for this? I'm using ruby on rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Ruby on Rails Problem. You can solve it by using JavaScript or http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-stopwatch-using-css3-without-images-or-javascript

For the JavaScript approach just google for stopwatch or timer and JavaScript.